# What is the KPL protocol?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-kpl-integration.html

> The Kinesis Producer Library (KPL) runs in a separate process, and communicates with your parent user process using IPC. This architecture is sometimes called a microservice, and is chosen for two main reasons:
>
> ...
>
> 2) Arbitrary clients can be supported
>
> There are always customers who use languages other than the ones officially supported. These customers should also be able to use the KPL easily.

How can I "easily" use the KPL IPC? What's the protocol?